# Как сделать зарядку планшета по microusb, если этот разъем занят устройством

Tags: android, usb, arduino

Привет. Есть планшет. Подключаю к нему через MicroUSB плату Arduino. Так как в данной схеме хостом является планшет он питает плату и постепенно разряжается, а чтобы его зарядить нужно подключить зарядку через этот уже занятый порт. Что можно сделать, для того, чтобы и зарядка шла, и планшет с платой работал одновременно? Планшет не жалко, можно паять, пилить, ломать, чтобы добиться результата.

Comment: Гугль в первых позициях по запросу https://www.google.ru/search?q=microUSB+%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA кучу ссылок на магазины дает.

Comment: Думал про это штуку, но не могу найти точной информации, что подключив ее и подав в одну дырку питание а в другую ардуину, то планшет будет питаться а ардуино общаться :)

Comment: @GlWhitefoot а если просто использовать USB HUB?

Comment: @LexHobbit Он не будет заряжать планшет.

Comment: @GlWhitefoot тогда вам это должно помочь https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1822653

Comment: *OTG MODE and CHARGING MODE ( unfortunately both modes wouldn't work at the same time )* решение -- использовать внешний блок питания для таблетки, если в ней нет разъёма, то вскрывать и подпаивать концы.